# Subsetting a dataframe by multiple stepwise conditions in R

Tags: r, survey

I am looking for a way to subset a data frame by multiple conditions. My data set is comprised of respondents with at least one and a maximum of 4 children who are either biological children or stepchildren, which I am looking to filter for each child respectively.

Thus, I am currently filter the data like so: `SUBSET03 <- subset( SUBSET02, (ehc9k1 == 1 | ehc9k1 == 3) | (ehc9k1 == 1 | ehc9k1 == 3) & (ehc9k2 == 1 | ehc9k2 == 3) | (ehc9k1 == 1 | ehc9k1 == 3) & (ehc9k2 == 1 | ehc9k2 == 3) & (ehc9k3 == 1 | ehc9k3 == 3) | (ehc9k1 == 1 | ehc9k1 == 3) & (ehc9k2 == 1 | ehc9k2 == 3) & (ehc9k3 == 1 | ehc9k3 == 3) & (ehc9k4 == 1 | ehc9k4 == 3) ) #S`

This doesn't work out - any tip on how to 'replace' the brackets?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your logic, be aware that

`(ehc9k1 == 1 | ehc9k1 == 3)` can translate to `ehc9k1 %in% c(1, 3)`. assuming the variable ehc9k1 measures the number of children,

Your logic is incorrect. if you want to have a number between 1 and 3, you would have to use either `ehc9k1 %in% c(1, 2, 3)` or `dplyr::between(ehc9k1, 1, 3)`

which is shorter, reduces the number of brackets

Otherwise, I like to use `dplyr::filter()` with `if_any()` or `if_all()`
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html

```r
library(dplyr)

SUBSET03 <- SUBSET02 %>% 
  dplyr::filter(
    # if_any will return rows that match the condition at least once 
    # if_all will return rows that match the condition for all column
    if_all(.cols = c(ehc9k1, ehc9k2) , \(x) x %in% c(1, 2, 3))
  )


SUBSET03 <- SUBSET02 %>% 
  filter(
    if_any(.cols = c(starts_with("ehc9k") , \(x) x %in% c(1, 2,3))
  )
```

You can use select helpers to capture multiple columns names if they have a common pattern
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html

It would help if you provided a working example if I didn't answer your question correctly.